# MapStruct - Can't map property Optional<LocalDate> to LocalDate

Tags: java, option-type, mapstruct

*NOTE: This is unlike other questions on StackOverflow because they resolve this issue by mapping the two classes manually. Since ScheduleSource and ScheduleTarget are exactly the same classes, I want them to be mapped automatically.*

Hi,

I have 2 classes ScheduleSource and ScheduleTarget. They have exactly the same properties.

When I try to use MapStruct to map from ScheduleSource to ScheduleTarget, I get the error:

```
  Can't map property "java.util.Optional<java.time.LocalDate> startDate" to "java.time.LocalDate startDate". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.time.LocalDate map(java.util.Optional<java.time.LocalDate> value)
```

I have attached the two files. Can you please help?

Files are:

- ScheduleSource, ScheduleTarget - the two Java Beans
- ScheduleMapper - the mapping class.
- **ScheduleMapper.java**

> ```
> package testStructMap;
>
> import org.mapstruct.*;
> import org.mapstruct.factory.*;
>
> @Mapper
> public interface ScheduleMapper {
>   ScheduleMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( ScheduleMapper.class );
>
>   ScheduleTarget scheduleSourceToScheduleTarget(ScheduleSource scheduleSource);
> }
> ```

- **ScheduleSource.java, ScheduleTarget.java - same structure**

> ```
> package testStructMap;
>
> import java.time.LocalDate;
> import java.time.LocalTime;
> import java.util.Optional;
> import javax.validation.constraints.*;
>
> public class ScheduleSource {
>   @FutureOrPresent
>   @NotNull
>   private LocalDate startDate;
>   @NotBlank
>   private String repeatType;
>   @Positive
>   private Integer occurrences;
>
>   public Optional<LocalDate> getStartDate() {
>       return Optional.ofNullable(startDate);
>   }
>   public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
>       this.startDate = startDate;
>   }
>
>   public String getRepeatType() {
>       return repeatType;
>   }
>   public void setRepeatType(String repeatType) {
>       this.repeatType = repeatType;
>   }
>   public Optional<Integer> getOccurrences() {
>       return Optional.ofNullable(occurrences);
>   }
>   public void setOccurrences(Integer occurrences) {
>       this.occurrences = occurrences;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mapstruct, but I can guess it maps different objects :)

If your source and target classes have the same structure then the problem is

```
public Optional<LocalDate> getStartDate();
public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate);
```

So it gets the Optional object and tries to pass it to a method accepting a LocalDate.

So your possible ways of action are

1. change getter to return a simple object
2. change setter to accept an optional (which is fine I guess, but
   seems a bit off)
3. declare a mapper method

Comment: Really good answer. I would jus like to add to this, MapStruct should support such mappings and I would ask you if you can to open an issue in the MapStruct issue tracker https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues. Note: I am one of the MapStruct developers

Answer (score 3):

In 1.3.0.beta1 the following is supported:

```
 package testStructMap;

import org.mapstruct.*;
import org.mapstruct.factory.*;

@Mapper
public interface ScheduleMapper {
  ScheduleMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( ScheduleMapper.class );

  ScheduleTarget scheduleSourceToScheduleTarget(ScheduleSource scheduleSource);

  default <T> T unwrapOptional(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional.orElse(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. MapStruct still complains about the optional:

Comment: For the moment use this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313504/743507

Comment: Yes but in this case the person wants to convert the source from Object to Optional because the target is Optional. So the unwrapOptional method does not help in this case, why there are 2 Vote points?

Comment: @HardSystem: source and target are the same according to the writer. Hence `public Optional<Integer> getOccurrences()` needs to be mapped to `public void setOccurrences(Integer occurrences)`. The solution provides a mapping method called by MapStruct that makes the conversion requested, taking the optional source to the target. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

*Map target Optional to source which is not Optional how can we make it follow the example below:*

```
@Named("HelperClass")
class Helper {
    @Named("convertToOptional")
    public Optional<KontaktpersonVerwandtschaftsgradTyp> convertToOptional(KontaktpersonVerwandtschaftsgradTyp optional) {
        return optional != null ?  Optional.of(optional) : Optional.empty();
    };
}

@Mapping(target = "kontaktpersonVerwandtschaftsgrad", source = "tdfFall.kontaktpersonVerwandtschaftsgrad", qualifiedByName = { "HelperClass",
            "convertToOptional" })
```

*and also we need to add uses and the name of the Helper class*

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { Helper.class })
```

Comment: You assume that source is NOT null. 'Optional' will be returned as NULL in case of source is null