# Use Java 8 optional with Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have these two classes:

```
public class CustomerEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private int age;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

and

```
public class CustomerDto {
    private Long customerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Optional<String> address;
    private int age;
}
```

The problem is that Mapstruct doesn't recognize the Optional variable "address".

Anyone has an idea how to solve it and let Mapstruct map Optional fields?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not yet supported out of the box by Mapstruct. There is an open ticket on their Github asking for this functionality: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/674

One way to solve this has been added in the comments of the same ticket: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/674#issuecomment-378212135

```
@Mapping(source = "child", target = "kid", qualifiedByName = "unwrap")
Target map(Source source);

@Named("unwrap")
default <T> T unwrap(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional.orElse(null);
}
```

As pointed by @dschulten, if you want to use this workaround while also setting the option `nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS`, you will need to define a method with the signature `boolean hasXXX()` for the field `XXX` of type `Optional` inside the class which is the mapping source ([explanation in the docs](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check)).

Comment: Note that this workaround fails with NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, an empty optional counts as non-null, so null will be applied.

Comment: As a workaround to the workaround, add a `hasXXX` method alongside the `Optional getXXX` method, see https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check

Comment: Nice workaround to the workaround! I'm going to include it in the answer later :)

Answer (score 1):

New solution: `return repository.findById(id).map(entity -> mapper.toDTO(entity));`

Older solution: People seem to have problem after upgrading from mapstruct 1.3.1 to higher verion. so the new workaround would be:

```
@Mapping(source = "child", target = "kid")
Target map(Source source);

    @Reference
    public static <T> T unwrapReference(Optional<T> optional) {
        return (optional != null && optional.isPresent()) ? optional.get() : null;
    }
```

expecting you have imported the mapper, you can use it something like this:

`Optional.ofNullable(kidMapper.toKidDTO(KidMapper.unwrapReference(kidRepository.findById(chatId))));`

answered by janinko in this issue: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2295