# MapStruct map Optional Object to none optional fields and also use formatting

Tags: java, mapstruct

I want to map subfields of the Optional object to a none Optional object and use also formatting.

These are not small classes to write the mappings all by hand...

I did try to take the object out, using the @named, however it still can not find the object using the source attribute in the @mapping, it gives only the option of "present" or "empty" which are boolean in the source attribute.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<A> {
....

    @Embedded
    private AApproval approval;
    
...
getters setters


//THIS IS IMPORTANT, getter is optional !!!
    public Optional<AApproval> getApproval() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(approval);
    }
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class AApproval {
....
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "approval_date", nullable = true)
    private LocalDateTime approvalDate;
.....
getters setter toString ....
}
```

want to map to this

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-04-23T12:23:23.456347+02:00[Europe/NA]")

public class A   {
....

  @JsonProperty("approval")
  private AApproval approval = null;

getter setters...
}
```

```
public class AApproval   {

...

  @JsonProperty("approvalDate")
  private String approvalDate;

...


  public AApproval approvalDate(String approvalDate) {
    this.approvalDate = approvalDate;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get approvalDate
   * @return approvalDate
  */
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "20230228125959", value = "")


  public String getApprovalDate() {
    return approvalDate;
  }

  public void setApprovalDate(String approvalDate) {
    this.approvalDate = approvalDate;
  }
}
```

and mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AMapper {
    @Mappings({
            
            @Mapping(target = "plannedDate", source = "plannedTime", dateFormat = MiscUtil.YYYY_MM_DD),
            @Mapping(target = "approval.approvalDate", source = "approval.approvalDate", dateFormat = MiscUtil.yyyyMMdd_HHmmss),
            ...... })
    A toModel(somepackages.other.A source);

}
```

also already tried to do this but still fails to generate

```
    @Named("unwrap")
    @Mapping(target = "approvalDate", source = "approvalDate", dateFormat = MiscUtil.yyyyMMdd_HHmmss)
    default AApproval approval(Optional<somepackages.other.AApproval> optional) {

    }
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313504/3816852) not exactly what I am looking for.